# Updating Table from other Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table housing information about current projects at my workplace (main data table). I am trying to make a table in a separate tab which stays up-to-date with the main data table, but at the same time allows me to sort the data. The idea is that managers can create multiple reports from the data without having to re-enter their criteria each time (ex. HVAC projects sorted by risk factor in one tab, electrical sorted by risk factor in another, etc.). These reports should automatically update when new data is added to the main data table. This is for management (not me) to use, so I'm trying to make it as simple as possible.
I have tried using array formulas, but these don't allow sorting. I have tried custom views, but these don't preserve sorting order. I have tried pivot tables, but these seem more suited for numerical summaries. I am extremely frustrated and stumped. Unfortunately, I became so frustrated earlier that I deleted my attempts at making the auto-updating tables :(. I still have the main data table, fortunately!

Does anyone have recommendations? Let me know if more information would help! I am using excel 365.

Thomas Kennings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating a linked cloned sheet:**

Follow these steps to create a reference cloned sheet including formula that will mirror changes on the main sheet. You can also create a VBA macro to generated linked clone sheets quickly, but its easy enough to do manually:

1. Create a copy of the main sheet: Right-click the sheet name, click "Move or Copy", checkmark "create a copy" and click "OK". (This way we get the original formatting but will replace all values with formula linked to the source data in the steps below.)
2. Edit cell A1 in the new sheet with the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A1),"",Sheet1!A1)`
3. Now copy cell A1 (CTRL+C), select all (CTRL+A) or preferably a smaller relevant area, paste (CTRL+V), hit CTRL for the paste pop-up menu, choose Formula only (press F)

**Caveats:**

- You might have to extend the cloned sheet formulae beyond the last row and/or column, so that new data added would also reflect (this would unfortunately not include any formatting applied to the new data)
- Formatting changes on the main sheet does not auto-update (you can however use format painter to reapply changes to the clone)
- If you use filters in the cloned sheet, you would need to reapply the filter (ALT+CTRL+L) after making changes in the main sheet.

You could auto-reapply the filter using the Worksheet_change event in VBA, but that would require saving the spreadsheet as a macro-enabled file, with associated permission pop-ups and warnings - which in my experience with management - would just be cancelled/ignored/declined. Its better to just add a HUGE RED BANNER in the top row "HIT CTRL-ALT-L TO REFRESH REPORT".

**Flexible clone formula to deal with rows or columns being inserted:**

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$Z, ROW(), COLUMN())),"",INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$Z, ROW(), COLUMN()))
```

or more correctly (to account for inserting say a new column A, and prevent the above reference changing to Sheet1!$B:$AA)

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A:$Z"), ROW(), COLUMN())),"",INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A:$Z"), ROW(), COLUMN()))
```

Although the latter is volatile and thus CPU intensive.

In **Excel 365** you can do [the same with a single dynamic array formula](https://superuser.com/questions/1713596/how-to-have-the-data-from-one-sheet-put-onto-another-sheet-automatically-via-for) in a single cell A1:

```
=LET(usedrange, Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$Z,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1)), IF(ISBLANK(usedrange), "", usedrange))
```

Comment: This seems to work and be quite flexible! However, when I add a new entry to the main table the filter excludes that new entry. For example, if there was no risk number of 25 in the dataset yet and I add a project with a risk number of 25, the filter automatically deselects 25 after being refreshed. Have you encountered this issue before?

Comment: If I select in the filter on the clone sheet numbers 1, 3, 5 (2 and 4 unchecked) then add a new number 6 to main, the 6 remains unchecked (since you only wanted 1, 3 and 5). Makes sense to me. If you want it to default to be included, you might have no choice but to reset the filter (CTRL+SHIFT+L twice) or to code in some VBA.

Comment: I just realised, my solution will fail if you insert new rows in between old rows. Its fine if you only edit existing rows, or enter new data into existing blank rows, but as soon as you insert, the references in the cloned sheet would become noncontinuous.  I'll update my solution.

Comment: That's a good point--my wanting the filter to adjust conflicts with my wanting the filter to remain fixed. Doh! I think the report tool will be good enough with some reminders to check the filters place in the banner at the top. Thanks so much for your help!