# Excel (MacOS) Find all values in one column, select adjacent and move

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, worksheet-function

I've been struggling to figure this out and how to phrase a question properly for a search, if it's out there already please link.

Here's an example expenses sheet:
[image]

How would you select all cells with numerical value for a 'Train' row and move them to the column Transport?

I.E. I want to select D5,D6,D11 and move them to F5,F6,F11 (as a batch, without dragging each one individually (naturally I'm working on a much larger sheet than the example).

I'm on MacOS and the 'Find All' function apparently doesn't exist in Excel for Mac. But even if I had that function, to Find All 'Train' entries, I'll still wouldn't now how to select adjacent connected numerical values, and move them to column F for Transport.

Any help is profoundly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is this a one time thing or a recurring task? If the former, you could sort on the first column, then copy the values over

Comment: Thanks, that's not a bad idea actually. I can choose a range, sort by selected column a-z, move to a diff. column, and then re sort by date column (which I didn't include in the example). It's something I do a lot, and I was sort of wondering if it were possible to do on a much larger sheet, spread across months, even years. But resorting I can do it month to month...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome!

**Moving multiple selections**

This is an interesting problem that perhaps Excel hasn't quite yet solved! Selection groups or "masks" cannot be moved or shifted on its own as its always attached to the data/cell you have selected. As you rightly point out, even if you could "find all" "train" cells it would still just select from column A and not from column D. You could write a VBA macro to shift the selection to column D (which would be overkill), but that still doesn't really help, as Excel doesn't maintain the positions of multiple selections on a copy and paste (i.e. copy D5,D6,D11 would simply paste as F5,F6,F7).

The suggestion by @cybernetic.nomad to sort by column A is possibly the best move (no pun intended), as it also overcomes the multiple selection issue above. You can sort, cut and paste, just don't "filter" for "train" as this only hides the rows in between and would still cause problems. If you are worried about returning the spreadsheet to the original order (across multiple months), you can (before sorting) add a helper column say in G, put a 1 in G1 then select all of G and Home > Fill > Series to number G as 1,2,3,4... . Now sort via transaction, complete the move, and re-sort via helper column F.

**Alternatives**

Of course you could also just record and modify a macro to do the move for you and assign the macro to a button or a shortcut key.

Lastly you could "clone" the whole table with formulas in a new sheet, and modify the formula for F to pull in values from D if A is train. I detailed how to create a [linked clone sheet here](https://superuser.com/questions/1706430/updating-table-from-other-table/1706441#1706441) but in essence, in a new sheet put this formula in A1 and copy down and across.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A1),"",Sheet1!A1)
```

Now modify the formula in D

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!D1),"",IF(Sheet1!A1="Train", "", Sheet1!D1))
```

and in F

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!A1="Train", ISNUMBER(Sheet1!D1)), Sheet1!D1, IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!F1),"",Sheet1!F1))
```

The ISNUMBER is just to check that you haven't corrected this train entry before.

Comment: Thanks both! That's how I ended up approaching it, with 'nomad's' suggestion to use Custom Sort and a helper column, I called it 'REF#'. I found that when I sorted the transaction column, A-Z, moved data between columns, and then resorted according to date, they were no longer in sequence by transaction order, but by A-Z and then date, so I worked out that I needed an extra REF column to be able to re sort everything according to transaction order. Thank you so much, I'll experiment out the Macro approach and maybe learn something.