# Apply formula on filtered result

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like Excel to work on a dataset where one `source` sheet would contain my dataset and a `metrics` sheet would contain my computed values.

I would like to be able to autofilters my source data and reference the filtered cells only in a formula.

For example, if a cell of `metrics` contains `=SUM(source!B:B)` I would like it value to be updated upon filters.

Comment: so, you want [SUBTOTAL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939): `=SUBTOTAL(109,source!B:B)`

Answer (score 0):

By default, any normal Excel function will access referenced cell values without regard for its visual status (number formatting or hidden/filtered status).

So if even Sheet1!A1 is hidden or filtered, Sheet2!A1 can still reference the value `=Sheet1!A1`. You can however use SUBTOTAL or since 2010 use the improved AGGREGATE to perform any of up to 19 different functions and flag it to ignore other subtotals/aggregate functions, errors and/or hidden/filtered rows.

If you happen to use any of the 19 functions available via AGGREGATE, you can quite easily summarise your data as intended, and it will auto-update upon filtering the source.

However, if you require more complicated formula on all cells, you can generate a linked clone sheet like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1706430/updating-table-from-other-table/1706441#1706441) but modified to make hidden rows 0 if a number or "" if text:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Source!A1),"",IF(AGGREGATE(3,5,Source!A1)=0,IF(ISNUMBER(Source!A1),0,""),Source!A1))
```

So basically each cell in the source is individually referenced/duplicated to the summary sheet, but replaced with a 0 or empty string "" if blank or filtered/hidden. Semantically, the above formula reads:

```
If cell is blank, return empty string else
If cell is hidden and is a number, return 0 else
If cell is hidden and is text, return empty string else
Return the cell value.
```