# How to automatically fill excel until it reaches an endpoint

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is my excel sheet:

[image]

I want it to be filled like this:

[image]

I've done this by hand as an example but this is not convienent for a sheet with thousands of rows:

In other words, for each cell in the sheet, if there is an empty grid on the right, fill it to the right, if there is an empty grid at the bottom, fill it to the bottom. Until the grid below is no longer empty; stop.

Is there a shortcut or script to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create a [linked clone sheet](https://superuser.com/questions/1706430/updating-table-from-other-table/1706441#1706441)

**Step 2:** Modify the clone formula from row 2 and column 2 onwards to "fill down or right" if blank, e.g. in B2

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Main!B2), IF(ROW()>=COLUMN(), B1, A2), Main!A2)
```

For column A, you can never "fill right" and ROW is always bigger than column so fill down only

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Main!A2), A1, Main!A2)
```

And for row 1, you can never "fill down" and ROW is always smaller than column so fill right only

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Main!B1), A1, Main!B1)
```