# Reference to a Table from another worksheet messes up the order and leads to data inconsistency

Tags: microsoft-excel, cross-reference

I have a spreadsheet with two worksheets.
The first worksheet (Source Data) contains a Table with 3 columns:

[image: Source Data]

I'd like to show two first columns from that table on the second worksheet (Emails) so I use a formula to reference a particular column of the source Table:
[image: Emails]

And it would be nice if it is a table as well so I can sort/filter the data.

However, it leads to weird issues. For example, if I resort the data on the Source Data worksheet, insert a new row in between, or delete a row from the middle (shown on the screenshot below), the second worksheet breaks, and the value of the third column (`jdoe@acme.com`) appears for the wrong record (`Kate Ostin`):
[image: Emails - deleted row]

Converting the second table (Emails) to a range doesn't help.

What are the possible solutions? Basically, I need to establish a strong relationship between the first two columns containing references (First Name, Last Name) and all other columns (Email) on the second worksheet. Please help on how it can be achieved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumption:**

- Source is original data as values
- Emails sheet reproduce selected columns from Source using formulae
- Email column is being populated by hand for each listed person in the Emails sheet

**Requirement:**

A sort, delete or insert on the source sheet should also do the same with the  associated email

**Bad news:**

There is no way to implement such a strong relationship without some complicated VBA macro code. You are trying to link two separate sheets / databases using a cell reference, but there is no hardcoded unique ID in either sheet that can be used to find the one in the other. A row number is not unique because it will change upon an insert/delete/sort command.

**Solution 1:**

Keep one sheet with all the source data including the email column. Use "[new window](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/when-you-open-a-workbook-excel-may-display-multiple-windows-that-contain-a-copy-of-that-same-workbook-49887fd0-b6df-e08b-c706-27a0ffc9ab15)" or [cloned sheets](https://superuser.com/questions/1706430/updating-table-from-other-table/1706441#1706441) to create separate views of the same data.

**Solution 2:**

If need be, maintain two separate sheets/databases. Create a unique ID for each row, e.g. NameSurnameDate = JohnDoe20220328 in the source sheet, or just  NameSurname if duplicate names are unlikely. The "Emails" sheet will have a list of emails in one column and unique id's as text (not reference). You can use VLOOKUP to pull the full name and surname from the source sheet. Manually syncronise the two, or write VBA code to syncronise (search for new unique IDs in "Source" and copy to "Emails", search for unique Ids in "Emails" and delete, sort alphabetically afterwards).