# How to affiliate two separate pieces of data so that it always shows on the same row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a sheet that I intend to use as a workflow. You will see in the illustration below two outlined boxes.

Red box - is data that is being pulled from another sheet

Green box - this is manually entered information.

The issue that I am experiencing is that if the data being pulled over is sorted or altered in any way from its origin sheet, it changes the order on my workflow sheet...causing the green outlined part to no longer be affiliated with the data it is intended for.

So what I am trying to figure out is how I can affiliate the green data with its respective piece of data, so that no matter what changes with the red section, it will always show up next to it in the same row.

[image]

In case this comes up...this is how I am pulling the data over. `=@INDIRECT("'CL Upcoming'!C10")`.

Comment: `=@INDIRECT("'CL Upcoming'!$C$10")` ?

Comment: @Hannu That is how I am pulling the red section data over. It may not be relevant, but I added it in case it was.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to add IDs to both sections and match the two grouped sections by ID? Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Hmm? Not sure I understand you; but anyway: Select the cells in question and find "Name manager" in the ribbon - I have no access to Excel currently so cannot tell details.

Comment: @Hannu The red section data can change by being deleted or reordered in the sheet where it is derived from. When that happens, it changes the other in the sheet you see above. Well since the green section is not affiliated programmatically with the red section, the green cells fall out of place.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to implement such a strong relationship without some overly complicated VBA macro code. You are trying to link two separate sheets / databases using a cell reference, but there is no hardcoded unique ID in either sheet that can be used to find the one in the other. A row number is not unique because it will change upon an insert/delete/sort command.

Whether you use absolute references (e.g. Sheet1!$A$1), relative references (Sheet1!A1), indirect reference (INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1")), named ranges, or even indexed references (INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,1,1)), all of them use basically a row and column number as unique identifier. When you change the source, a row that was previously say row 2, will now be row 1. At best you can implement your own identifier, say "JDoe20220401" and then use VLOOKUP on those. You could implement a VBA database management sheet, where you exclusively add or remove items using a VBA form. Adding or removing would generate the key and add or remove it on both sheets.

That being said, its perhaps better just to use 1 sheet and clone it for different views. See [related answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1713231/reference-to-a-table-from-another-worksheet-messes-up-the-order-and-leads-to-dat/1713259#1713259).