# Excel. Is there a simple way to search and replace but with variable cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, say I have some cells that say `=C5` and I want to replace this in all cells for `=F5` I suppose all I have to do is some search and replace with said values.

However, what if I have some cells that say `=C5`,`=C6`, etc and I want to replace them with `=C5*F5` ,`=C6*F6`

As you can see I can not just replace it because the number referenced is changing.

My problem is I have to change 200 of these cells. How can I do it quickly and not one by one manually?

Answer (score 1):

Select the **Range** you want to Replace cells- click **Ctrl+F**- select **Relace** tab- **Find what** enter **C** and **Relace with** enter **F**- **Look in** select **Formula**- **Replace All**:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**How to use Excel text functions like MID and SUBSTITUTE on cell formula**

This solution assumes there no fixed pattern and that you cannot make use of normal relative references which auto-adjusts as you copy and paste. The concept is to create a new sheet, pull in the formulae as text from the main sheet, use text functions to fix the formulae, then use search and replace to turn the text values back into actual formulae.

1. Create a [linked cloned sheet](https://superuser.com/questions/1706430/updating-table-from-other-table/1706441#1706441)
2. Modify the formulae to rather return the formula of each cell as text e.g.

   =IF(ISBLANK(Main!A1),"",ISERROR(FORMULATEXT(Main!A1)&"*F"&MID(FORMULATEXT(Main!A1),3,1), Main!A1))
3. Once done, copy all the cells and paste as values
4. Hit CTRL+F, click the REPLACE tab, and search and replace all *=* with *=*. This may seem like a futile search and replace, but it forces text to be recognised as formula again.

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses relative cell addresses to automatically adjust row numbers or column letters when you copy and paste a cell. Normally, you do not have to edit each cell separately. Only edit one cell and copy and paste to the rest.

Say you have three existing formulae directly below each other:

```
=C5
=C6
=C7
```

If you now want to add, say "*F5" to each where the "5" automatically changes to the correct row number, you simply edit the first cell:

```
=C5*F5
=C6
=C7
```

Then copy the first cell and paste it over the next two cells. Excel will automatically adjust the relative references to

```
=C5*F5
=C6*F6
=C7*F7
```

However, if you do *not* want the "F5" to change row number, you can lock it down to an absolute reference "$F$5"

```
=C5*$F$5
=C6
=C7
```

If you copy and paste the first cell over the bottom two, Excel will adjust C5 (relative) but keep $F$5 fixed:

```
=C5*$F$5
=C6*$F$5
=C7*$F$5
```

**Tips**

- You can lock only part of a reference $F5 or F$5, depending if you want Excel to pin the column or the row during a copy and paste.
- If you "cut and paste" a cell, its own formula will not be adjusted.
- If you cut-and-paste cell C5 to cell G10, all cells referencing C5 will auto-update to G10.