# Return list of all unique values based on criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking to return a list of all outstanding packages.

For each unique Package Name, I want to return the package name and code that is **next** to be completed (Either In Progress or Not Started)

For example, if this is my data

| Package Name | Package Code | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 100-01 | Complete |
| Name1 | 100-02 | Not Started |
| Name1 | 100-03 | Not Started |
| Name2 | 200-01 | Complete |
| Name2 | 200-02 | Complete |
| Name2 | 200-03 | In Progress |

Then I want the output to be:

| Package Name | Package Code |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 100-02 |
| Name2 | 200-03 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Hi @zalt.... I didn't get one thing in your question - You write above that the criteria to select entries is "the package name and code that is next to be completed (Either In Progress or Not Started". Shouldn't by this criteria, `Name1` with code `100-03` also be selected?

Comment: Hi @SaaranshGarg, I want only the next sub-package to be completed - not all sub-packages that need to be completed. So "Name1" is split into 3 "sub-packages" or "activities", 100-01 is completed and 100-02 is the next to be completed. 100-03 is only completed after 100-02, thus in this list we only want 100-02.

Answer (score 0):

You need a helper column called "next up". Say in **D2**

```
=IF(AND(C1="Complete", A1=A2), "Next", "")
```

Now use an auto-filter on the list and filter for "Next".

If you want a duplicate/separate table, in Excel 365 you can use the FILTER function

```
=FILTER(A2:B10, D2:D10="Next", "")
```

In older versions you can use a complicated VLOOKUP* or array formula, or just create a [cloned sheet](https://superuser.com/questions/1706430/updating-table-from-other-table/1706441#1706441) and use the auto-filter on the clone.

*For VLOOKUP, insert a new column A and count the "Next" occurrences e.g. `=IF(E2="Next", A1+1, A1)`. Then VLOOKUP each number's first occurrence in column A and return columns {2, 3}.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365:

- I created a Table and named the data table `Packages`

  ```
  F2: =UNIQUE(Packages[Package Name])
  G2: =INDEX(FILTER(Packages,(Packages[Package Name]=F2)*((Packages[Status]="In Progress")+(Packages[Status]="Not Started"))),1,2)
  ```

F2 will Spill down the results
Select G2 and fill down as far as needed

[image]

*If you have an earlier version of Excel*

- Create a column with a distinct list of the package names

  - This can be done in various ways

    - Using a helper column
    - Using the Advanced Editor to remove duplicates
- Then use this formula in G2 and fill down:

```
=INDEX(Packages[Package Code],
    AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((Packages[Package Name]=F2)*((Packages[Status]="Not Started")
    +(Packages[Status]="In Progress")))*ROW(Packages)-ROW(Packages[#Headers]),1))
```